# Netlify redirect to external domain not routing to correct path

Tags: node.js, reactjs, render, netlify

I have really struggled with `netlify.toml` file trying and trying and finally the same initial configuration I made is now working but the path redirected is incomplete and with the wrong request type.
For starters this is my `netlify.toml`

```
[[redirects]]
  force = true
  from = "/api/*"
  to = "https://cascurry-imape.onrender.com/:splat"
  status = 200

[[redirects]]
  from = "/*"
  to = "/index.html"
  status = 200
```

Now I expect that when I try to login as my server side code has been written a post request is sent to `https://cascurry-imape.onrender.com/api/users/login` instead a get request is sent to this route `https://cascurry-imape.onrender.com/users/login` and if you pay attention the `/api` is missing from the get request which should be a post request.

[image]

When this is how I sent the request

```
export const userLogin = async (userinfo) => {
  const response = await axios.post(`/api/users/login`, userinfo, {
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
  });
  response.data && localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(response.data));
  return response.data;
};
```

Please help.. I am very stranded